# Is a FCM token reused?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

Suppose a FCM token is generated `abcd` and assigned to a user say `user 1` now this token is no longer associated to `user 1` as he uninstalled his app. Can this token `abcd` be assigned to some other user in future?

EDIT 1:

I know it is `unique` at a time. But if a token is not being used by anyone `abcd` will that be used again by some other user as it is still unique as `user 1` is using a different token?

EDIT 2:

The token I am referring to is the `device regestration token`.

Comment: Your token is referring to device registration token or?

Comment: Yes, the device regestration token.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple is **NO**

Google/Firebase practice is having a hashing algorithm to generate a long and non repeating id (usually associate with timestamp and other factors), which usually can be up to 20 characters or more, to ensure it is unique in the database (FCM device token db).

Therefore, it will always assign a new and unique token to the new device.  Won't reuse the token in any circumstances.

**[UPDATE]**

Thanks for your comment, now I have a concrete answer to your problem now.  Each token contains the particular [user meta-data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions), and other info including unique id etc.

So the token can only be revoked by the same user but cannot be use by others (because it contains the user meta-data).

Comment: Thank you so much. I just need to know the Source before accepting the answer.

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54853590/6744473) FCM registration tokens aren't associated with users at all, they are associated with app instances on specific devices. And perhaps the FCM page linked above has been changed since it was added, but there's nothing there to suggest that there's any user meta data associated with FCM registration tokens.

Comment: Although I think it's important to note that despite that _maybe_ a given token won't be issued more than once for a given application, that doesn't necessarily mean that the possibility that a user being assigned a preexisting registration token should not be dealt with. As because they are associated with app instances and not users, a user could log out and a different one log in, and the FCM registration token will be the same as it was for the other because the app instance is still the same.

Comment: If there is no logic that takes that into account, you could end up sending push notifications to the old user using their last known FCM registration token, but what ends up happening is that the new user ends up being the one that receives them because they're the one that happens to be logged into the app instance associated with that token at the time the push notification is sent.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation about GCM says that token is unique, I think the same applicable for FCM as well. 
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration

> To verify that they can send and receive messages, client apps must register with GCM. In this process, the client obtains a unique registration token...

Comment: I agree it is `unique` at a time. But if a token is not being used by anyone `abcd` will that be used again by some other user as it is still unique as `user 1` is using a different token?